# Obtaining the link direcly to one answer of a question

Tags: support, hyperlinks, sharing

Is there a way to obtain the link to one precise answer of a question (not *the* selected answer).

There are multiple answers, and I want to talk about one precisely inside a comment.

Comment: There's a "share" button/link on all posts.

Comment: Wow. Four answers, not one freehand circle... Meta quality is going down...

Comment: @Mat Better? Better. :P

Comment: Yes, much. Thanks @Doorknob.

Comment: I considered adding the freehand circle after my initial 'fastest gun in the west' post, but then I read [this topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179689/discouraging-minimal-correct-answers-for-fast-points) and reconsidered.

Comment: @Mat: Here's a pretty good one. That's what you wanted, right? http://i.minus.com/iDE9cF5H591GN.gif

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Not red. Not good.

Comment: I edited my post with a recursive freehand circle. Do I get bonus points now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the "share" link under any question or answer for a permalink.

This has an added benefit: if enough people click on that link that you shared, you will get [a badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/260/announcer)!

[image]

Comment: ANSWER-CEPTION!

Comment: I fully expect you to keep the score up to date....

Answer (score 3):

Under every answer there is a button named `share`. Just click on it.

> [image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is utterly unclear. Without any freehand red circle I have no idea what to click on here. -1

Comment: I thought it was only to share questions and answers to facebook... I never clicked on that button again.

Comment: @Bart - Here you go....

Comment: Ah, that's what you meant. So much more clear now. ;)

Comment: @StephaneRolland - Stack Exchange is not a social network. :)

Answer (score 2):

Click the share button underneath.

[image]

Comment: answer in an answer in an answer... brain cannot process this sorcery :P

Comment: *'To understand recursion, you must first understand recursion'*.